# display current subdirectory URL of webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, url

Having an issue with the following code, it displays the full URL of the current page, 
(eg, example.com/dir1) however I am looking to display the sub directories only (eg, /dir1/). Also having an issue where it does not display spaces properly, spaces show in html encoding `%20`. 
I have very little programming experience and any help would be greatly appreciated.
`<p3><script>document.write(location.href);</script></p3>`
EDIT
working on the following script, however am having trouble implementing it
`<script>str.replace("%20", " ")</script>`
any thoughts?

EDIT - answer which suited my needs, many thanks to [brettc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6614615/brettc)
`var url = location.href;
url = url.split("examle.com").pop();
url = decodeURIComponent(url);
document.write(url);`

Comment: You can't have spaces in URLs. `%20` is how spaces are represented in URLs, it's called url encoding. Also this has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best way, but a way none the less. 
You could just split the string by the `”/“` and take the last occurrence.

Also, decodeURIComponent() will decode the %20 to a space, as found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

```
<script>

var url = location.href;// get url, put in url variable
url = url.split("/").pop();// get last element separated by “/“
url = decodeURIComponent(url);// remove any %20
alert(url);

</script>
```

Note: this will alert everything past the last “/“.

Comment: was able to modify the code you provided to achieve exactly what I wanted, Many thanks!    `var url = location.href;
url = url.split("example.com").pop();
url = decodeURIComponent(url);
document.write(url);`